# Changing ScrollView "scrolled" color from default

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uiscrollview, scrollview

Is it possible to change the ScrollView default color for when a page is completely scrolled up/down?

It seems there is no native property in Xamarin.Forms to do this.

[image]

Comment: I’m not familiar with this, but you might have to find out how to do that on each platform (android, etc), and write a custom renderer for scrollview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be called an edge effect for scroll view. At least on Android platform.
Try to add this to android/app/src/res/values/styles.xml:
`<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">#eb4034</item>`
*with color you want.